# Where to install additional LaTeX packages?

Tags: latex

I have `texlive-full` installed on my system. For a particular article I would like to use the [Backus-Naur Form (BNF) package](http://ctan.org/pkg/latex-bnf), which [is not available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=latex-bnf.sty&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) in any of the LaTeX packages for Ubuntu.

Where should I install this package (or just the `.sty` file) in order for it to be recognised accross the system, just like the other packages installed with `texlive-full`?

Comment: Seems like you can add it to the directive at which the shell variable TEXINPUT points to (http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex209/contrib/tex-bnf/bnf.README).  Perhaps ask the question at http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This system does not have the `TEXINPUT` variable set. `texlive` must use some other mechanism to locate the packages it needs.

Comment: This question might help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20160/how-to-register-my-own-packages-or-classes-in-a-separate-drive-to-tex-live-insta